# monte carlo integration on a R^5 hypercube in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, montecarlo, numerical-integration

I need to write MATLAB code that will integrate over a R^5 hypercube using Monte Carlo.  I have a basic algorithm that works when I have a generic function.  But the function I need to integrate is:

∫dA

A is an element of R^5.

If I had ∫f(x)dA then I think my algorithm would work.

Here is the algorithm:

```
% Writen by Jerome W Lindsey III

clear;
n = 10000;

% Make a matrix of the same dimension
% as the problem.  Each row is a dimension

A = rand(5,n);

% Vector to contain the solution

B = zeros(1,n);


    for k = 1:n
        % insert the integrand here
        % I don't know how to enter a function {f(1,n), f(2,n), … f(5n)} that
        % will give me the proper solution
        % I threw in a function that will spit out 5!
        % because that is the correct solution.
        B(k) = 1 / (2 * 3 * 4 * 5);

    end

mean(B)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to integrate? Are you just trying to find the volume of the region? That's what integrating dA itself suggests to me.

Comment: Correct.  I need a Monte Carlo algorithm that finds the volume of a unit cube in R^5.  The volume is 1/5!

Comment: Did you forget to add the homework tag?

Comment: I did not. But this is HW, we just are not graded on programming.  Don't ask me to explain it.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. The way you compute a MC integral is typically I ~= V * 1/N * (f_1 + ... + f_N). How do you plan to use this formula to find the volume? Seems circular to me. Furthermore, how do you figure that the volume of the unit cube in R^5 is 1/120?

Comment: I know how the TYPICAL MC integral looks.  I need help with this special case. How do I get 1/120 --->  Fundamental Theorem of calculus. First int is 1/2, second 1/3, … 1/5.  Real simple.  We don't have an equation editor here that I am aware of…

Comment: This is the first time I have stumped the people at Stack Exchange…  To be clear I am integrating 1 over a R^5 unit cube.

Comment: By that logic, wouldn't the volume of a 1x1 square be 1/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%Question 2, problem set 1
% Writen by Jerome W Lindsey III

clear;
n = 10000;

% Make a matrix of the same dimension
% as the problem.  Each row is a dimension
A = rand(5,n);

% Vector to contain the solution
B = zeros(1,n);


    for k = 1:n
        % insert the integrand here
        % this bit of code works as the integrand
        if sum(A(:,k)) < 1
            B(k) = 1;
        end

    end
    clear k;

clear A;

    % Begin error estimation calculations
    std_mc = std(B);
    clear n;
    clear B;

    % using the error I calculate a new random
    % vector of corect length
    N_new = round(std_mc ^ 2 * 3.291 ^ 2 * 1000000);
    A_new = rand(5, N_new);
    B_new = zeros(1,N_new);
    clear std_mc;

        for k = 1:N_new
            if sum(A_new(:,k)) < 1
                B_new(k) = 1;
            end
        end
        clear k;

    clear A_new;

    % collect descriptive statisitics
    M_new = mean(B_new);
    std_new = std(B_new);
    MC_new_error_999 = std_new * 3.921 / sqrt(N_new);
    clear N_new; 
    clear B_new;
    clear std_new;

% Display Results
disp('Integral in question #2 is');
disp(M_new);
disp(' ');
disp('Monte Carlo Error');
disp(MC_new_error_999);
```

Answer (score 2):

In any case, I think I understand what the intent here is, although it does seem like somewhat of a contrived exercise. Consider the problem of trying to find the area of a circle via MC, as discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration). Here samples are being drawn from a unit square, and the function takes on the value 1 inside the circle and 0 outside. To find the volume of a cube in R^5, we could sample from something else that contains the cube and use an analogous procedure to compute the desired volume. Hopefully this is enough of a hint to make the rest of the implementation straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is about the point where I arrived at before I asked the question.  It sounds like you just proposing acceptance rejection.  My question is not how to theoretically solve this problem, but how to do it in MATLAB.

Comment: Ok, then why are you still sampling from the hypercube in order to compute its volume? It's quite obvious this won't work: the only possible output of your proposed function is a vector of identical function values [1,1,...,1]. Your problem here is definitely NOT just a MATLAB one. You need to sample from something other than the hypercube itself in order to gain any useful information.

Comment: ok…  That was stated in your previous response.  I don't have a proposed function.  I just hard coded the answer.  I have no idea how to solve this problem.  That is why I have asked for help but so far people have only stated to obvious.

Comment: I don't think I'm being too cryptic. The Wikipedia example shows how to find the volume of a circle by inscribing it in a square. How might you instead find the volume of a square by inscribing it in a circle? How would this generalize to R^5? It's possible there is an easier technique that still meets the requirements of the problem, but from what I can tell your problem is: "Find the volume of the unit hypercube in R^5 using Monte Carlo rather than by direct computation." The volume should be 1, by the way, since the volume of a multi-dimensional interval is simply the product of its sides.

Comment: Well then perhaps I have poorly described the integral, because the The volume was given as 1/120.  When I integrate it analytically that is also what I get.  So for at least those two reasons your answer is of no use.  ∫dA = 1/120,  A is an element of R^5, and the bounds of integration for all 5 variables is [0,1].

Comment: I wan not saying that you were cryptic, merely unhelpful.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here a bit since the numbers you give as "correct" answer don't match to how you state the exercise (volume of unit hypercube is 1).

Given the result should be 1/120 - could it be that you are supposed to integrate the [standard simplex](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex) in the hypercube?

The your function would be clear. f(x) = 1 if sum(x) < 1; 0 otherwise

Comment: Well the integral I gave in the question is correct.  Perhaps the confusions was in me calling it just the hypercube and not the standard simplex.  What I wanted help with was in the if function in matlab.  I kept getting syntax errors.  Any how I figured out the solution: